# ClassCastException at OIS

Tags: java, object, classcastexception, objectinputstream, bag

Im getting a CCE when im reading an object in from a bat file.

loader class:

```
public static void loader()throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
  try{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("students.dat");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    while(true){
      try {
       stud = ois.readObject();
       student = (Student) stud;
       studentBag.add(student);
      }catch(EOFException e){
         break;
    }  
   i++;
  }
 ois.reset();
 ois.close();
 fis.close();
}catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
 System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

The CCE error im getting is at the line: student = (Student) stud;

The specific error code im getting is
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [LBags.Student; cannot be cast to Bags.Student

Im also not sure where its getting LBags,student from... i dont have any package or class or anything named LBags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string `[LBags.Student` is an internal type signature for `Array of Bags.Student`.  The first character `[` indicates an array, and the `L` indicates a reference type.

So, the message is saying you are trying to cast an array of `Bags.Student` to a `Bags.Student`, which is clearly not possible.  Thus, your serialized data contains an array, not a scalar object.

A complete list of type signatures is available in the [JNI Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html).  For completeness here is the list copied from that document:

```
Type Signature

Z                          boolean
B                          byte
C                          char
S                          short
I                          int
J                          long
F                          float
D                          double
Lfully-qualified-class;    object of class
[type                      Array of type
```

Comment: That list actually is helpful!!